# Adding background in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a background to a tkinter window, and it is not working. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

top = Tk()

C = Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)

filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Karthik\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\bank.png")

background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

C.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

I tried this, but I'm getting `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\Karthik\OneDrive\Pictures\bank.png"`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see my edit to better understand how to format questions.

Answer (score 1):

PhotoImage doesn't read .png files, but PIL.Image() does. Try using this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Karthik\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\bank.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

Check [this page](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) for more info.

Comment: But i am still getting the same result---ERROR

Comment: Have you read the link I provided? Can you provide the full error you're getting?